# `insert into` query syntax error

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to save data to the database and I get a syntax error for this query:

```
insert into attendance (Type) values (Holiday) where `Date`=2017-10-10
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please share some error information

Comment: Why _wouldn't_ you get as syntax error from this query?  You didn't put single quotes around your date literal.

Comment: What does `Holiday` represent?

Comment: Holiday is a column, not a string

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into attendance (Type) values (Holiday) where `Date`=2017-10-10
```

Is not correct at all. - You can NOT use the WHERE clause in the INSERT. - Insert is for new rows.

If you need to change the values where date is = '2017-10-10', you should use UPDATE.

```
UPDATE attendance SET Type = 'Holiday' where Date='2017-10-10'
```

The "Type" column name shouldn't be a problem ..